# Reinforcement learning - Find optimal number of values to randomly sample to optimize random forest classification

Tags: r, optimization, reinforcement-learning

I have data set up like the following:

```
control1 <- sample(1:75, 3947398, replace=TRUE)
control2 <- sample(1:75, 28793, replace=TRUE)
control3 <- sample(1:100, 392733, replace=TRUE)
control4 <- sample(1:75, 858383, replace=TRUE)
patient1 <- sample(1:100, 28048, replace=TRUE)
patient2 <- sample(1:50, 80400, replace=TRUE)
patient3 <- sample(1:100, 48239, replace=TRUE)
control <- list(control1, control2, control3, control4)
patient <- list(patient1, patient2, patient3)
```

To classify these samples as either control or patient, I want make frequency distributions of presence of each of the 100 variables being considered. To do this, I randomly sample "s" values from each sample and generate a frequency vector of length 100. This is how I would do it:

```
control_s <- list()
patient_s <- list()
for (i in 1:length(control))
        control_s[[i]] <- sample(control[[i]], s)
for (i in 1:length(patient))
        patient_s[[i]] <- sample(patient[[i]], s)
```

Once I do this, I generate the frequency vector of length 100 as follows:

```
controlfreq <- list()
for (i in 1:length(control_s)){
controlfreq[[i]] <-
    as.data.frame(prop.table(table(factor(
        control_s[[i]], levels = 1:100
    ))))[,2]}
patientfreq <- list()
for (i in 1:length(patient_s)){
patientfreq[[i]] <-
    as.data.frame(prop.table(table(factor(
        patient_s[[i]], levels = 1:100
    ))))[,2]}
controlfreq <- t(as.data.frame(controlfreq))
controltrainingset <- transform(controlfreq, status = "control")
patientfreq <- t(as.data.frame(patientfreq))
patienttrainingset <- transform(patientfreq, status = "patient")

dataset <- rbind(controltrainingset, patienttrainingset)
```

This is the final data frame being used in the classification algorithm. My goal of this post is to figure out how to identify the optimal "s" value so that the highest balanced accuracy is achieved. I am using "rf" from the caret package to do classification.

```
library(caret)
fitControl <-trainControl(method = "LOOCV", classProbs = T, savePredictions = T)
model <- train(status ~ ., data = dataset, method = "rf", trControl = fitControl)
```

How can I automate it to start "s" at 5000, change it to another value, and based on the change in accuracy, keep changing "s" to work towards the best possible "s" value?

Thanks!

EDIT: I am defining accuracy as the follows:

```
selectedIndices <- model$pred$mtry == 2
confusionmatrix <- table(model$pred$obs[selectedIndices], model$pred$pred[selectedIndices])

BalancedACC = ((confusionmatrix[1,1]/length(control))+(confusionmatrix[2,2]/length(patient)))/2
```

This is the value I want to maximize by changing "s".

Comment: I'm not sure how you could learn the optimal step towards a new `s` because it is likely not a convex problem. What you could do is to use *grid search*.

Comment: Grid search will only work for optimizing caret, right? I'm looking for some machine learning algorithm which will help me determine an optimal s value. Sure, I could keep guessing values and seeing accuracy, but there are several other places in my program that need a similar machine learning solution. If I limited the bounds of s would that make it more likely? I was thinking for example, start at 5000, change to 6000, if accuracy increased, increase s further, else decrease, etc, until it found the best value possible. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm looking for a type of reinforcement learning, I'm just not sure how to implement it.